# Changing full disk encryption password

Tags: disk-management, encryption

Is it possible to change the full disk encryption password after installation?

Comment: I have deleted the passphrase but it still asks me for it when i boot my laptop. Why i type in my old passphrase it says: "No key available with this passphrase". Please help! ☹️

Comment: I think if you delete your passphrase and don't create another one it will lock you out of the disk. Thanks for raising this issue, I will modify the answer accordingly so others don't suffer the same fate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up a terminal and type:

`sudo cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda5 -S 0`

If you want to add another passphrase:

`sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda5`

If you want to see which keyslots are enabled:

`sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5`

If you want to erase keyslot #1:

`sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sda5 -S 1`

DO NOT erase the last remaining keyslot without creating another one or you'll lock yourself out of the disk.

Hat tip to the good ole [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Adding_LUKS_keys)

Comment: What password does this change

Comment: The default (key slot 0) full disk encryption password created by the Elementary installer

Comment: You can find out what drive you need to use (rather than `/dev/sda5`, which is specific to Seth's setup) by typing `lsblk --fs` at a terminal and looking for the line that says `crypto_LUKS`.